“ValueError: Unrecognized model type” when loading my trained custom transformer model
I have trained a transformer model as a sequence-to-sequence model, did not finetune an LLM.
However, my way of saving the model into huggingface or even locally seems to be incorrect, meaning that checkpoints, weights and other important model configurations may have not been saved properly.
because when I try to load it from huggingface, it gives me this error:
ValueError: Unrecognized model in Lu...... Should have a model_type key in its config.json, or contain one of the following strings in its name: albert, align, altclip......

Please find the layout of my work in this notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qwT4mqaTPoVW7HwlWNRKheR7FAzIdR-L#scrollTo=DtU3whBevE31

The error specifically indicates that the config.json file associated with your model does not contain a model_type key.
This key is necessary for the Hugging Face Transformers library to recognize and correctly instantiate the model architecture.
To resolve the issue, update your config dictionary to include the model_type key:
config = {
  "model_type": "seq2seq_transformer", # can be replaced with a custom type in code
  "architecture": "Seq2SeqTransformer",
  "vocab_size": tokenizer.vocab_size,
  "d_model": d_model,
  "num_layers": num_layers,
  "num_heads": num_heads,
  "dim_feedforward": dim_feedforward,
  "save_steps": save_steps
}

For custom models, update the library's configuration and model mappings:
from transformers import CONFIG_MAPPING, MODEL_MAPPING

CONFIG_MAPPING.update({"seq2seq_transformer": CustomSeq2SeqConfig})
MODEL_MAPPING.update({"seq2seq_transformer": CustomSeq2SeqModel})

Save the model weights using the save_pretrained method:
model.save_pretrained("./model_dir")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("./model_dir")

Now when loading the model, the library will use the model_type in the config.json to find and instantiate the corresponding class:
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

AutoModel = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("./model_dir")

If the above doesn't work:
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer

# Load the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("./model_dir") 

# Load the custom model type
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("./model_dir", config=CustomSeq2SeqConfig.from_pretrained("./model_dir")) # CustomSeq2SeqConfig must be created as class model type


Please check config.json, pytorch_model.bin (or equivalent model weights file), and tokenizer files (vocab.json, merges.txt, tokenizer_config.json, etc.)
This should resolve the missing model_type key issue and the unrecognized model name problem, ensuring your custom model can be loaded correctly using the Hugging Face Transformers library.

Thank you for your valuable response, very appreciated.
In updating the mappings of the transformer library, it is unclear what these variables hold: CustomSeq2SeqConfig and CustomSeq2SeqModel?

is CustomSeq2SeqConfig same as config. and CustomSeq2SeqModel is my trained model?
